# Multiple SQL statements in a soapUI JDBC test step

Tags: sql, soapui

Hi is it possible to have 2 sql query in JDBC step?

`Select * from Student where student_id := StudentID;`

`Select * from Employee where employee_id := EmployeeID;`

Comment: why do you want to do so?

Comment: @Rao I just want to see results for 2 tables that's all

Comment: I should not be an issue  to achieve with  two steps then.

Answer (score 0):

If you really, absolutely have to execute two (or more) SQL statements in the same JDBC step, you can:

[image: soapUI-multiple-sql]

Your response set will just contain two (or more) `ResultSet` elements that you can assert on in the usual way.

Comment: Multiple SQL statements works in MSSQL, but in IBMDB2 it does not work. it return SQL error code -401

Comment: A DB2 -401 error indicates the operands of a statement were incompatible. Do the statements work individually when you execute them at the DB2 CLI?

Comment: Yes, it only works when there is NO semicolon, but when I put semicolon even though I only have 1 SQL statement it returns -401

Comment: Sounds like a peculiarity of DB2. That leaves you the only option of using two separate JDBC test steps.